# I have a bat file that needs to run in powershell, via the start-process command is slow

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script that runs a bat file, it has to run in powershell as it is being called by an application that can only run powershell (not bat files)

I use the Start-Process command

```
start-process -FilePath D:\versioned\pf_trunk\deployment\environments\development\aws\deployment\awx\development\files\PublishMYPlanetFootprint.bat -Wait
```

The batch file runs some visual studio builds and then moves some files.

If I run the batch file on its own, it runs and completes and closes the command window.

When I run it in powershell, it runs, completes and closes the command window, however the script continues to run for another 17 minutes before timing out.

I thought the wait would only wait for the bat to finish and then terminate.

Can somebody help with my powershell.  What am I missing to ensure the script terminates on completion of the bat file operation.

Thanks

Comment: Does (Start-Process -FilePath D:\versioned\pf_trunk\deployment\environments\development\aws\deployment\awx\development\files\PublishMYPlanetFootprint.bat -PassThru).WaitForExit() work?

Comment: I will give that a try ..thanks

Comment: PowerShell is more powerful than the Windows command processor. So why not recoding the batch file content as PowerShell code? I think this would be definitely the best solution here.

Comment: Hi Mofi, thanks and I would prefer to use PowerShell however I am stuck because it has to be used in 2 systems, one uses Powershell the other only runs bat files so I wanted 1 common bat file (as it has the most code) and a powershell wrapper

Comment: When you use `-Wait` the batch process shouldn't be lingering after the call returns unless it had spawned child processes. Do you get the same behavior if you use `& C:\path\to\your.bat` or `cmd /c C:\path\to\your.bat`?